# Skip storyboard cleanly in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, controltemplate

I have a Style for a ToggleButton which defines a ControlTemplate. My ToggleButton is animated when it changes states, but i don't want it to animate when i navigate to a new page. So, i added an EventTrigger on the Loaded event with SkipStoryboardToFill to avoid this behavior, and it does what i want.

My only issue now, is that when i add a new ToggleButton, it tries to skip storyboards which haven't been started, generating an Animation Warning ("Unable to perform action because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive control.") which seems to impact my application's performance.

I could probably work around that but i'd rather solve the actual problem. Is there a way i could add a condition in my EventTrigger ?

```xml
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Loaded">
        <SkipStoryboardToFill BeginStoryboardName="checkedSB" />
        <SkipStoryboardToFill BeginStoryboardName="uncheckedSB" />
    </EventTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                 Value="true">

        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="checkedSB">
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                    <ThicknessAnimation To="20 1 2 1" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="uncheckedSB">
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                    <ThicknessAnimation To="2 1 2 1" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>

    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: You could consider a multidatatrigger. Set the tag or an attached property of the togglebutton a half second after it's loaded.  Or.  Use another property of your viewmodel combined with an IsLoading flag in there.  Set this property from the setter of your ischecked (bound) property only once isloading is false.

Comment: Eventually, i switched to using EventTriggers on the Checked and Unchecked events and it seems to be working fine. Not sure why it didn't occur to me earlier.      I don't really have a ViewModel that i can tune, the ControlTemplate is in my application's resource dictionary.     Not setting this as an answer since it is not a solution to the actual question, which is more about conditions in EventTriggers.

Comment: Ah i was reminded why EventTriggers weren't a solution. If anything triggers them before the page is loaded, the storyboards are started but cannot find the elements referenced by TargetName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way i could add a condition in my EventTrigger ?

Short answer: No.

An `EventTrigger` always applies when the corresponding event is being raised.

If you want to trigger the animations conditionally, you should either switch to using a `MultiDataTrigger` or implement the animations programmatically.